# How can I change the "action" in a form through JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Quite honestly, I am stupefied why this is not working, though it seems pretty straightforward. All I want to do is change the action attribute of a form through in a HTML file through Jquery. However when I try it out, I am getting "no file exists at address localfolder/variableName".

Here's the Jquery:

```
$('form#varName').attr('action', 'http://link.mydomain.com/' + realURLTail );
```

The HTML is :

```
<form id="varName" method='get' accept-charset='UTF-8' name='oi_form' action='variableName'>
```

I am probably missing something very simple. The substitution of the variableName from the referenced ID in the Jquery is not coming through. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle with all the components in place? It would be much easier to debug, and you might find your answer in the process.

Comment: When do you run the jQuery command?  I.E. what event triggers it?

Comment: check wheather `$('form#varName').length > 0`

Comment: thanks Guys - nickyt's response did the trick - I knew it was simple (for him :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your form has an ID, just do this:
`$('#varName').attr('action', 'http://link.mydomain.com/' + realURLTail )`;

And here's a fiddle of it in action, http://jsfiddle.net/nickyt/HUszu

Comment: that worked like a charm - thanks a ton. When do you use the [form] before the ID and when do you leave just the ID without the [form] in Jquery?

Comment: You don't. It's not a valid CSS selector. If you wanted to use the form element in the CSS selector, you could do something like this $("form[name='oi_form']"). Having said that, anytime you have an ID for an element, use that in your CSS selector as it's the quickest way to find an element. I highly recommend the jQuery documentation, and in your case, the CSS selectors section, http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/